# How to send a string with security, iphone

Tags: iphone, encryption, securestring

How to send a string in most securely.
Got some issue with encryption.
My encrypted value in iPhone is not similar to webapp.

So please suggest the most secured form of sending a string from iphone (except encryption).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Send it with ssl. Which is in fact encryption but one you don't have to care about.

Comment: you're looking for a method which only use `Encryption` not `Hashing`? Are you trying to send passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no secure way of sending a string without using encryption. If you're sending passwords, which means that you don't need to be able to reproduce the original string, you could just send hash values.

If you have to be able to reproduce the original string I guess the easiest way is to just use SSL. If you don't want to buy an expensive certificate, you could use a self-signed certificate and bundle it with the application.